# This logic should find the number of pairs in array with difference d but only the sample test case passes

Tags: c++, algorithm

For this array(sample test case): 1 1 2 2 4 6 and D = 2
the number of pairs with difference D is 3.
Explanation:
Here the pairs of difference 2 are (2,4) and (4,6). There are 2 ways to generate (2,4) and there is 1 way to generate 4,6. The output is 3 (1+2).
This code pass this test case only but it doesn't pass all other test cases (about 13 hidden test cases). I need to understand why does this happen

```
int Func_M_2(vector<int> arr,int D)
{
    int counter =0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<arr.size();j++)
            {
                if(arr[j]-arr[i]==D)
                counter++;
            }
        }
return counter;
}
```

Comment: `std::abs(arr[j] - arr[i]) == D`?

Comment: Does your code assume the array is sorted? Does the question make that guarantee?

Comment: no it doesn't assume that

Comment: Have you tested it with an unsorted array?

Comment: @Jarod42 same output

Comment: Check with `{6, 4}`.

Comment: @Alan Birtles I did it works. ex: 8 6 9 10 1 4 3 output is 2

Comment: What is the maximum array size? You may have a problem ot time limit.

Comment: @Damien
it gives 0 which is the right answer

Comment: @Damien
it gives 0 which is the right answer

Comment: arr size is between 3 and 10^7. @Damien

Comment: the code doesn't fail in time. it gives wrong answer for all other test cases

Comment: Is not `(6, 4)` a valid pair?

Comment: @Damien
which array we took this pair from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240014/discussion-between-eslam-ashraf-and-damien).

Comment: your example still has the pairs in order, if they aren't in order it doesn't work, e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/xK6hcTx7h

Comment: Also fails for D == 0, since it will count all entries as pairs with themselves

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cannot post a comment but I think the difference D must also be abs(D) in your if():

```
if( abs(arr[j]-arr[i]) == abs(D) )
```

Comment: You seem to be the only one who noticed that D could be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void solve()
{
    int difference=2;
    vector<int> numbers={1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6};
    vector<int> vectorCount;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0; j<numbers.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(numbers[i]-numbers[j]==difference)
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        vectorCount.push_back(count);
    }
    int summarize=0;
    for(int i=0; i<vectorCount.size(); ++i)
    {
        summarize+=vectorCount[i];
    }
    cout<<"summarize <- "<<summarize<<endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
summarize <- 3
```

Comment: it should give the same answer

Comment: Could you explain what you've changed and why? Answers just containing code aren't very helpful

Comment: @Alan Birtles, All differences, satisfying to the command-branching ```if(numbers[i]-numbers[j]==difference)```, will be added into the parameter-container ```vectorCount```. After that all numbers, containing into the ```vectorCount```, must be summarized.

Comment: clarifications should be [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70305366/edit) into your answer